# Accessing forks in private GitHub repository

Tags: github

I am the owner of a private GitHub repository. Somebody else (student1) forked it a while ago and has done some work on his fork. Now I need somebody else (student2) to pull those changes and work off of them. However, he cannot access student1's fork at all. Trying to git pull provides an error about not being able to find it. Student2 can also not see student1's fork on GitHub's website.

Everybody is added as a collaborator. I can access all forks (I am the original owner of this repository). I tried removing student2 and adding him back but it changed nothing. I tried inviting another friend (let's say student3) and he can fork but also cannot see other forks. In the past, I distinctly recall any users added as collaborators being able to pull from other forks so I am not sure why this isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

All I see is "[Find another repository to fork](https://help.github.com/en/articles/fork-a-repo#find-another-repository-to-fork)"

> You can fork any private repository you can access to your user account or any organization on GitHub Team or GitHub Enterprise in which you have repository creation permissions.

Maybe this is possible through an organization, where you [can change member privileges](https://help.github.com/en/articles/allowing-people-to-fork-private-repositories-in-your-organization).

Comment: Thanks but creating the fork isn't really the issue and our organization can't currently host private repositories I don't think